ImapCapabilities special characters
With Mailkit i would like check if my server accept '+' in e-mail
I thought it was necessary
if (!_imapClient.Capabilities.HasFlag(ImapCapabilities.UidPlus))
OR
if (!_imapClient.Capabilities.HasFlag(ImapCapabilities.LiteralPlus))
but it doesn't work
the service that I am creating will receive emails but I would like to put a condition that if the mailbox accepts the '+' character to be able to configure my service
Do you have any idea how to check this ?

What does "accept '+' in e-mail" mean? uidplus and literalplus don't have anything to do with that characted, the plus in both names refers to improvements, like how a product may be named 'Foobar Plus' or 'Foobar Gold Elite' even though the product neither performs addition nor contains gold.

thank you, accepting the '+' in the email means being able to receive emails like this: "toto+tata@domaine.com"

That’s not something capabilities will tell you.  Email addresses are basically opaque, so usually you already know who you’re sending an email too.

Oh, that's called subaddresses and is not something you can learn from the IMAP server. If you want to autodetect it, I suggest probing the incoming SMTP server. If you know that your address is juduno@example.com, and that server rejects RCPT TO:<8493284923482390481290@example.com> but accepts juduno+583940238490@example.com, then it may be assumed to accept subaddresses. At least well enough that you could ask the user.

Thank you for your response, I will set this up now.

Oh, that's called subaddresses and is not something you can learn from the IMAP server. If you want to autodetect it, I suggest probing the incoming SMTP server. If you know that your address is juduno@example.com, and that server rejects RCPT TO:8493284923482390481290@example.com but accepts juduno+583940238490@example.com, then it may be assumed to accept subaddresses. At least well enough that you could ask the user. –
arnt
